# Vector space basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hey can some help me with this practise question I don't even know where to start thanks

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $\{v_1, \dots , v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Show that $\{v_1,v_1+v_2, \dots ,v_1+ \dots +  v_n\}$
is also a basis for $V$.

Comment: Are the elements in $\{v_1,v_1 + v_2, \ldots, v_1 + \ldots + v_n\}$ linearly independent? Do they span $V$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show that any vector $v \in V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors $\left\{ v_1, v_1 + v_2, ..., v_1 + \cdots + v_n\right\}$ (the set spans $V$) and that it is a linearly independent set. The first part is fairly trivial by way of finding the generalized expansion coefficients. For the second part, you need only show that the only solution to

$$
c_1v_1 + c_2(v_1 + v_2) + \cdots + c_n(v_1 + \cdots + v_n) = 0
$$

is the trivial one, namely $c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0$.

Comment: what if you are not taught/allowed to use the generalized expansion coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

If $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis, and $A$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, then if
$$
w_i = A(v_i), 1\leq i\leq n
$$
then $\{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n\}$ forms another basis (why?).

Now just check that the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
\ldots \\
\ldots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is invertible.